# OpenMP doesn't run this for loop in different threads, how can I fix it

Tags: c++, multithreading, opencv, optimization, openmp

I have this code:

```
#pragma omp parallel for
for( i=0;i<(int)table.size();i++)
{
    Vec3b bgrPixel;
    TableElement element=table[i];
    bgrPixel = inputImage.at<Vec3b>(element.InputPixel.y,element.InputPixel.x);
    outputImage.at<Vec4b>(element.OutputPixel.y,element.OutputPixel.x)[0] = bgrPixel[0];
    outputImage.at<Vec4b>(element.OutputPixel.y,element.OutputPixel.x)[1] = bgrPixel[1];
    outputImage.at<Vec4b>(element.OutputPixel.y,element.OutputPixel.x)[2] = bgrPixel[2];
    outputImage.at<Vec4b>(element.OutputPixel.y,element.OutputPixel.x)[3] = 255;
}
```

when I run it, I can see that only 25% of my processors power is used. I believe it is not run in parallel. Why it is not run in parallel and how can I improve its performance?

Images are OpenCV mat objects.

Comment: What's the size of the table? Also, what's the value of OMP_NUM_THREADS ?

Comment: The table is relatively big (around 100K entry) and my system can have up to 4 thread. I have another loop in the same application which runs in parallel and my cpu usage during that loop is 100%.

Comment: The logic inside the loop seems pretty simple (I'm not familiar with your code so please correct me if I'm wrong). So 4 threads performing a few simple assignations each might not be consuming. So maybe the low usage is expected. Try increasing the number of threads and see what happens.

Comment: @GabiTurliu OK I will do it, but the whole loop tools around 5 sec on my i7 laptop. I need a way to reduce this time. My CPU can run 4 thread in parallel so I think using 4 thread is optimum.

Comment: Have you tries to explicitly specify a scheduling clause e.g. `schedule(dynamic)`? cf http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenMP#Scheduling_clauses

Comment: A stupid question - do you enable OpenMP support while compiling the code? There are virtually no compilers nowadays that have this support turned on by default and one has to explicitly enable it: `-fopenmp` for GCC, `-openmp` for Intel, `-mp` for PGI, `/openmp` (or the corresponding option in project settings) for MSVC++.

Comment: Another possible cause would be if the `at()` method implements internal locking of the matrix data and thus prevents concurrent access. Consult the manual.

Comment: @HristoIliev: Yes OpenMP is enabled as I can see that another for loop that I have in the same application, runs n parallel.

Comment: @HristoIliev: how can I check at() function? How can I access buffer without using at function?

Comment: @QuentinGeissmann: Added schedule clause but no difference.

Comment: Look at the source code of OpenCV.

Comment: How about simplifyed for-loop `int sz = (int)table.size();` + `#pragma omp parallel for` `for(i=0;i<sz;i++) {...}` ?

Answer (score 0):

It was suggested in the comments, that Mat::at might do some kind of locking. I checked the OpenCV source, and this does'nt seem to be the case. One version of Mat::at is reproduced below:

```
template<typename _Tp> inline _Tp& Mat::at(int i0, int i1)
{
    CV_DbgAssert( dims <= 2 && data && (unsigned)i0 < (unsigned)size.p[0] &&
        (unsigned)(i1*DataType<_Tp>::channels) < (unsigned)(size.p[1]*channels(⇉
        CV_ELEM_SIZE1(DataType<_Tp>::depth) == elemSize1());
    return ((_Tp*)(data + step.p[0]*i0))[i1];
}
```

It would seem to me that as suggested in the comments, the reason for low CPU usage is most probably that your code doesn't have much anything to do for the CPU. As the code is just simple memory assignments, your code is probably memory, not CPU bound. My suggestion is that you look into not copying the data (the OpenCV Mat format is very flexible about pointing to the same data with two matrices by just creating a new header). If the InputPixel and OutputPixel values are uncorrelated or have a compex correlation, you probably need to resign to the fact that accessing memory randomly (i.e. lots of cache misses) is going to take some time.